# installing Ububtu 16 using bootable flashdrive

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

Hi this is my first Ubuntu installation, and I am really glad to get out of Windows! I am installing Ubuntu 16 on Acer Aspire using a bootable flashdrive. It is taking a long time - 18 hours to complete 1/3 installation. Firefox is already operating and working fine, but can I suspend the install and complete it later without losing what I have? Can I reboot now to get to other programs? I connected to internet for the install, which might be the cause of the slow installation. I want to pause the installation and restart later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's taking so long and you can already use it..
Did you start it as a LiveCD ?
Also I would suggest to install through the CLI that would probably be faster (Nothing explains 18 hours unless you are doing a upgrade and installing loads of things from internet and your internet connectivity is very slow).
And if you are still installing and stop it you will lose what you have already, but if that's the case of the 18 hours I would suggest you to start again. Maybe try a different USB port.

Comment: I think you would have combined to install the third party software from internet and this will also update the packages. Stop the installation and start again without third party software's.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should stop the installation to save your more time, and try installing again.

Since installation from flash drive should not take more than 1 hour (at max) normally it takes 20-30 minutes.

You are telling that you have connected to Internet, that most likely doesn't affect installation on that level, but you can try to choose to `not to connect to Internet` for next try.

The possible cause would be: May be your flash drive is slow or corrupted
 OR
 third party software you choose to installing are downloading from Internet and that is taking more time.

for next try choose`not to connect to Internet`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I restarted installation without internet. It said it could not create partitions, but gave option to skip and do that later. It is stuck on 'creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0 (sdb) and no further activity.

Comment: if you have still windows installed on you computer open it and from disk management . On the partition (you want to install Ubuntu) right click and select delete, it will turn black colour, then try to install Ubuntu. If Windows not there.  then during Ubuntu installation delete the partition (by selecting partition and choose "minus" sign) then try to install.

Comment: Windows is already wiped.

Comment: During Ubuntu installation delete the partition (by selecting partition and choose "minus" sign) then try to install.If here is nothing on drive delete all partitons one by one then install.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to understand this (not too experienced in tech) - In the installation menu it says: sda1 (fat32) 15.6GB and sda2 (unknown) 32.3 kb  Under that is Device for boot loader installation: /dev/sdb ATA Toshiba MQ01ABFO (500.1 GB)  The choices are quit, back, install now. What do I do now?

Comment: Also under device is: /dev/sdb1 495932 MB Unknown; /dev/sdb5 swap 4172 MB unknown. Are these the partitions on the hard-drive?

Comment: Okay, I deleted the partitions. There is an option for 'New Partition table' Do i go there, or just hit 'install now'?

Comment: Though you are not dual booting still just watch this video once OR download it for watching again. It explained everything. You can skip to 06:00 min.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU

Comment: I tried it again and it gets stuck on 'creating ext4file system in / partition'. I installed on another laptop using same flashdrive and works great, so I am concluding that the hard-drive is damaged.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yeah may be your hard drive have some problem.And you welcome.